# Can I solve the -505 error in Play store as the app Developer? (non Adobe air app)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop, failed-installation, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm having an app that its current update is failing to a part of the users saying error "-505" when they try to update the app via Play Store, and it happens on Lolipop only.

After some search in the internet, I found that it could happen to my app in case it would be Adobe Air based app, which is not the case. I read also about duplicate permission for GCM, but m app does not work with GCM.

Most of the stack overflow posts are saying that all i need to do it to tell my users to perform factory reset... which i'd like not to do, cause i have just too many users like that..

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This issue is infuriating. I just had a huge uptick. Is this a samsung problem now?

Comment: I found solution to that few days after i asked the question. The problem caused by the same authority in content provider that my app had in its manifest. Since Lollipop released, Android does not permit non unique authority string in content provider anymore. So the shortest solution for that is just to add to authority string the package name of the app

Comment: The only content provider in my manifest is  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" and I've always had android:authorities="my.package.name.fileprovider" with it. Can you give an example of what you changed?

Comment: This is how my content provider written : <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
android:authorities="my.package.name.com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234" android:exported="true" />  If what causes the problem is what caused it in my case, you should have another already installed app that has the same string there. I found the solution by reading the bug report that one of my users sent me.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to that few days after i asked the question. The problem caused by the same authority in content provider that my app had in its manifest. Since Lollipop released, Android does not permit non unique authority string in content provider anymore. So the shortest solution for that is just to add to authority string the package name of the app.

This is how my content provider written and works:  I found the solution by reading the bug report that one of my users sent me.